# Test a python function in Robot Framework 3

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

How can I test a python function in Robot Framework 3. The code I want to test is:

```
def message(msg):
  print ('your message is ' + msg)
  return True
```

The robot test:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Lib

*** Test Cases ***
Case1
    message    "hello"
```

Comment: this wiil be given me error like

Comment: Case1                                                                 | FAIL |
No keyword with name 'message' found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Valid Login                                                           | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file with python functions in it, you need to reference the filename with suffix in the robot test (assuming your file is named `Lib.py`).

Example:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Lib.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the below steps to get the function called from within robotframework,

Step 1: Create a python file with the function as follows
C:\Users\kgurupra\pyfirst.py

```
def message(msg):
    print ('your message is ' + msg)
    return True
```

Step2: Make sure your .py file in the PYTHONPATH - THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT STEP

Step3: Create your robotfile as mentioned below,

```
*** Settings ***
Library           String
Library     Collections
Library         Selenium2Library
**Library         pyfirst.py**

*** Variables ***
${robotVar} =            FooBarBaz
${MY_DATA_TABLE_VALUES_TEMP}  {"foo": "this is foo", "bar": "this is bar"}


*** Test Cases ***
Case1
    message    "hello"
```

Step4: You should see the output as mentioned below,

```
(rf1) C:\Users\kgurupra>robot rbpy.robot
==============================================================================
Rbpy
==============================================================================
Case1                                                                 | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Rbpy                                                                  | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\Users\kgurupra\output.xml
Log:     C:\Users\kgurupra\log.html
Report:  C:\Users\kgurupra\report.html
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

```
def message(msg):
    return ('your message is ' + msg)
case1=message("hello")
```