# How to compare two JSON responses on Robot Framework?

Tags: json, robotframework

I'm trying to find a library that contains a keyword to help me with that and didn't succeed.

What I'm doing at the moment is converting each JSON response to a dictionary and then comparing the dictionaries, but I hate it.

I was trying to find similar libraries and found this python code, but I don't know how to make this function works to me.

```
def _verify_json_file(self, result, exp):
    '''
    Verifies if two json files are different
    '''      
    with open(exp) as json_data:
        data = re.sub(ID, ID_REP, json_data.read())
        expected = JSON.loads(data)   
    differences = jsondiff.diff(expected, result, syntax='explicit')

    if not differences :             
        return True
    if differences == expected or differences == result:
        raise AssertionError("ERROR! Jsons have different structure")
    return False
```

Comment: Clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**APPROACH#0**

To make the above function work for you you just have to create a python file and put your function in that file and keep that file in the PYTHONPATH and use the same in your robot code by calling it in settings section using Library keyword. I have answered this question in detail with all the steps mention in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47918971/test-a-python-function-in-robot-framework-3/59042972#59042972).

1. Create a python file(comparejsons.py) with the above code in it
2. Keep the above python file in PYTHONPATH
3. Use Library    comparejsons.py under settings section in your robot file

**APPROACH#1**

1. You should create a custom keyword which makes use of the below library and then compare the 2 jsons.
2. You can make use of "robotframework-jsonvalidator" [module](https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-jsonvalidator/)

Sample code below,

```
*** Settings ***
Library    JsonValidator
Library    OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
Check Element
    ${json_example}=    OperatingSystem.Get File   ${CURDIR}${/}json_example.json
    Element should exist    ${json_example}    .author:contains("Evelyn Waugh")
```

**APPROACH#2**

After converting the JSON to a dictionary you can just make use of the Built-in keyword , here , values=True is imortant.

```
Dictionaries Should Be Equal<<TAB>>dict1<<TAB>>dict2<<TAB>>values=True
```